# What are the rr pins on an sram?

Tags: pins, sram

I've been using an IBM [liberty](https://vlsiuniverse.blogspot.com/2016/12/liberty-format-introduction.html) (cell library) file for some SRAMs, dating back to 2007. [For copyright reasons, I can't post the content here]. I don't have the datasheet, and I've been trying to work out the functionality of the pins.  I've worked out most of them - pins like `CLK`, `d` and `q` are obvious -, but there are a few like `bundle (rr)`, which for a 256x47 SRAM contains 20 pins in 4 groups of 5. Probably related to that are 4 `rre` pins which I guess are the enables for the `rr` pins.

The best I've managed to find on Google is that some SRAMs have different modes like Register-Register (RR), Late Write (LW) and Late Select (LS) modes.

Comment: What the heck is "an IBM liberty file"? What is the manufacturer and part number of the SRAMs? 256x47 sounds *extremely* specialized, and without a datasheet, there's no way we could possibly guess about the function of the pins.

Comment: @DaveTweed - it might possibly be a register file device, They were quite commonly used for processor registers in early designs. 'rr' bits are likely used for register addresses.

Comment: I was kind of expecting people here to know what a liberty file is. It's the cell characterization file (timing and power) produced by foundries. The SRAM isn't a discrete component, it's a cell to be included in an ASIC design.

Comment: Ha! never knew that... I, and everyone I have ever worked with, has always called them "library", or "lib" files... who, besides @PaulFloyd knew they were "Liberty" files? Fantastic then! Can we change the name to "lib/rary files" please? Oh, and FWIW, I was going to say what Peter said, as my wild guess.

Comment: Row repair and row repair enable maybe? I knew the term liberty, btw :)

Comment: Nah, row repair doesn't add up. 4 groups means each covers 64 rows, and there are 5 bits per group, which would cover 32 rows. It also seems like RAS overkill, but you never know with IBM. You're not actually building a chip without a datasheet for a component are you?

Comment: @Matt No I'm using it as an input for an EDA tool.